# Importable Menus? Along with Pages (a site layout template)

Tags: menus, import, export

Simply stated:

How do you pre-create menus which can be imported by a user who does not want to spend a day recreating the wheel?

Most themes have preferred layouts, which can have a tedious page and menu set up. Exporting pages for later import -- easy. **But how do you export menu items for later import?**

Answer (score 0):

Menus are included in native WordPress export. It's not too convenient that natively you can't *only* export menus though. From quick look up there is [WordPress Menu Exporter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-exporter/) plugin available in official repository for that.

Export/import aside there are more options to automate it, such as set up scripts with WP CLI or simply using PHP code to detect empty menus for the purpose of generating defaults or prompting user to do so.